# Laravel 8 Search with Pagination is not working properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to do search with pagination but I am stuck with this **GET** error.

```
function search_document(Request $request){
    $result = Document::where("title","like", "%".$request->input('query')."%")->paginate(5);
    return view('/admin/documents')->with(["documents"=>$result]);
}
```

Error I got

1. URL changed to /api/search_document that has to be like /admin/documents
2. I am getting this Error

[image]

Route is like this :

```
Route::post("search_document",[adminDocumentController::class, 'search_document']);
```

Blade File Code

```
<form action="/api/search_document" class="main__title-form" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Find document" name="query">
                        <button type="submit">
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

Please help me

Comment: Change your route `Route::post…` to `Route::get…`

Comment: Then How I will pass query data to the Route?

Comment: I am using a Form to perform Search Action

Comment: Can you post your `form` code with your question

Comment: Form Code Added @sta

Comment: You can simply change `method="POST"` to `method="GET"` and also from route. By default laravel pagination uses the get parameter

Comment: I did that, But Getting 404 error, and URL looks like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search_document

Comment: is your url correct ? did you place your route in `web.php` or `api.php` ?

Comment: it is in api.php

Comment: what url is for the form ?

Comment: My form URL is  **<form action="/api/search_document" class="main__title-form" method="GET">** and When I click on search Button y URL looks like this **http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_document?query=eco**

Comment: I don't know why there is ? before query

Comment: not your form action. which url did you use to see the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your route from post to get, then
in your controller method will receive request as parameter, your form method should also be GET,

check this material out [How to implement search functionality in laravel 8](https://dev.to/kingsconsult/how-to-implement-search-functionality-in-laravel-8-and-laravel-7-downwards-3g76)